# AWS Parse deploy con Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: aws, parse.com

Estoy investigando un poco los aws y me he encontrado con un muro, a ver si alguien me hecha una mano.

Al hacer el [deploy de parse](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) me crea una instancia, una ip elástica, un s3 etc.
Lo único que hay que hacer es conectar un servidor con mongodb, 
[recomiendan mlab en esta guía.](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

El problema es que una vez conectado con su configuracion `MASTER_KEY`,`APP_ID` y `DATABASE_URI` no consigo acceder al parse mediante la ip : us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse
Este es el mensaje que me da la web en cualquier ruta.

> Congratulations
>   Your first AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js application is now running on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?
Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Si ya tienes una base de datos creada, esta tiene un grupo de seguridad.
Puedes verlos en:

EC2->Security Groups.

Simplemente tienes que habilitarle un puerto en la pestaña de inbound.

Para base de datos es:

```
All TCP
TCP
0 - 65535
sg-XXXXXXX(El grupo de seguridad de tu elastic beanstalk).
```

Luego en tu aplicación simplemente le das los datos de conexión a la base de datos.